# Unisex names on a ketubah

Tags: halacha, names, marriage, ketubah

In Israel there are many names that are unisex; used for both men and women. What is the halacha regarding using a traditionally boys name for a girl and vice versa with regards to writing those names on the ketubah?

For example, Daniel and Danielle are both spelled דניאל in Hebrew. I came across this exact issues which was apparently resolved by writing the female version as דניעל. I'm unsure if this is particular to the name דניאל which is a male Jewish prophet but I could imagine such an issue arising with other Tanach names, of men or women, being used in modern times for the opposite sex. Given that such a change was made I imagine that a normal rendering of the name may invalidate the ketubah somehow?

What is the halacha regarding this?

In a related question: if two people have the same non-Tanach name (e.g. both Maayan or both Ori or both Shachar etc. which are unisex*), does the exact same name go on the ketubah for the husband and wife in the situation that they both only have one name?

*Disclaimer: I've not checked whether these names are found in Tanach! Please edit accordingly.

Comment: what do you see as potential halachic issues? The use of "ben" or "bat" would ensure that the reader knows to whom the text is addressing.

Comment: I added a sentence hopefully to clarify. The fact that her name was changed from דניאל to דניעל tells me that דניאל could invalidate the ketubah since דניאל is a "male name". If relevant, this was how the London Bet Din acted in this case.

Comment: I would think changing her name in the document would be more a cause for invalidating, as it isn't her name.

Comment: There is a practice to use Yiddish-esque spelling for non-Hebrew names. Since Danielle is not a Hebrew name, that's probably why they went with דניעל which is a straight Yiddish-esque transliteration of the name. I don't see why gender would have anything to do with it.

Comment: also, two other small notes (which are not central to your question) -- one is whether Daniyel was a prophet, and the second is whether that is teh spelling of his name https://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t3401.htm

Comment: Shouldn't we ignore this orthography stuff and use ליאור or שמחה instead?

Comment: @Kazi אין מערבין שמחה בשמחה